Why does .Net ContentDisposition encode this filename incorrectly?
This is a very niche event, which occurred once in over 10,000 submitted filenames. However, the following code generates what looks like an invalid ContentDisposition:
    var fileName = "AAA_AAAAAAAAA AAAAA (AAAA – AAAA &  – )";
    var cd = new ContentDisposition{
        FileName = fileName
    };  
    
    Console.WriteLine(cd.ToString());

Those are n-dashes (U+2013), not hyphens. The result (which includes a \n and consists of two lines) is -
attachment; filename="=?utf-8?B?QUFBX0FBQUFBQUFBQSBBQUFBQSAoQUFBQSDigJMgQUFBQSAmICDigJMg?=
 =?utf-8?B?KQ==?="

I've reduced the filename to the smallest use-case I can find. What's odd is change any character, and the result is valid - for instance, remove the first A and you get
attachment; filename="=?utf-8?B?QUFfQUFBQUFBQUFBIEFBQUFBIChBQUFBIOKAkyBBQUFBICYgIOKAkyAp?="

I'm curious why the framework gets this wrong? All other filenames fit on one line so I'm not sure what's special about this one.
(The particular issue I see - storing the ContentDisposition as stored as a Tag in Azure file storage, and when it's generated in this way over two lines, it causes an error.)

For clarity, what exactly do you think has gone wrong with the encoding?

FWIW the line break appears to happen whenever the filename is encoded and the line length exceeds 60 characters (a filename like –AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA also triggers it), which in my understanding is an RFC2231 thing?

Beware, the ContentDisposition class in .net is used for email, not http.

To add to what shingo said, you probably want to work with ContentDispositionHeaderValue. You can use SetHttpFileName and it'll then correctly produce filename and filename* values as used in HTTP.
